# SFMC SOAP API RetrieveRequest resulting in "An error has occurred and has been logged by our system."

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap

I'm trying to get a list of query definitions whose "QueryText" is "like" a certain value. Here's the XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <s:Header>
        <fueloauth>
            accessTokenHere
        </fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>QueryDefinition</ObjectType>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>DataExtensionTarget.Name</Properties>
                <Properties>DataExtensionTarget.CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>QueryText</Properties>
                <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>QueryText</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>Lead</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here are my headers and the service URL:
[image]

Yet, when I click Send, I get the below response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Error</title>
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" />
        <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="C#" />
        <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript" />
        <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" />
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Arial;">
        <table style="height:100%; width:100%;" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="height:10%; background-color:#808080">
                <td>
                    <div style="color:#ffffff; font-size: 16px;">An error has occurred and has been logged by our system.
                        <br />
                        Thank you. </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td>
                    <div id="errorTxt">&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've seen a similar Stack Exchange post on this but that didn't help me any. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that you need to set the SOAPAction header to "Retrieve" (with double quotes)? This is how I send my SOAP calls from POSTMan.

Answer (score 0):

I put my template here. I also faced a similar issue like yours. Eventually I managed to make it work by changing the header. Try this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">Access token goes here</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
        </Options>
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>QueryDefinition</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtensionTarget.Name</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtensionTarget.CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
        <Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
           <q1:Property>QueryText</q1:Property>
           <q1:SimpleOperator>like</q1:SimpleOperator>
           <q1:Value>Contact_Salesforce</q1:Value> <!-- content in the query -->
        </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```